# getYahooData() in R does not like my for loop, but manually looping works

Tags: r

I am trying to build a table of stock data.  When manually setting i=1, i=2, etc, and stepping through this for loop, I can build the table.  When I run the loop, I get the error below.

```
library(TTR)
#For loop C = build table using getYahooData function
pull.append <- NULL
TomsTickers2 <- as.data.frame(c('A','AA','XLF','XLV'))
For(i in 1:length(TomsTickers2[,1])){
      i <- as.character(TomsTickers2[i,1])
      pull <- getYahooData(i,20150601,20150714,freq = 'weekly',adjust = F) #Get data
      pull <- data.frame(Date=index(pull),coredata(pull),Symbol=rep_len(i,length(pull[,1])))
      pull.append <- rbind.data.frame(pull.append,pull)

}
```

Error Message:

```
pull <- getYahooData(i,20150601,20150714,freq = 'weekly',adjust = F) #Get data

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

Comment: Your error is that you've written `For` not `for` so the code is parsing wrong. Fix that and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is that you've written `For` not `for` so the code is parsing wrong. Fix that and it works fine. R is case-sensitive.

(if you prefer you can remove the question rather than accepting the answer. or accept the answer and keep this question up for posterity).